# Cloudant error "required index service unavailable" when trying to create text index

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to create a text index from the cloudant dashboard for cloudant local. I am getting an error that says "required index service unavailable". This is the index request payload that I am sending

```
{"index":{},"type":"text"}
```

Comment: Could it be that you're using an old version of Cloudant Local that doesn't have Cloudant Query text indexes? Emailing support@cloudant.com is probably your best bet.